# c# Buffer explanation

Tags: c#, arrays, buffer

This might be a really beginer's question but I've been reading about this and I'm finding it hard to understand.

This is a sample from the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer(v=vs.110).aspx) page about this subject (just a little smaller).

```
using System;

class SetByteDemo
{
    // Display the array contents in hexadecimal.
    public static void DisplayArray(Array arr, string name)
    {
        // Get the array element width; format the formatting string.
        int elemWidth = Buffer.ByteLength(arr) / arr.Length;
        string format = String.Format(" {{0:X{0}}}", 2 * elemWidth);

        // Display the array elements from right to left.
        Console.Write("{0,7}:", name);
        for (int loopX = arr.Length - 1; loopX >= 0; loopX--)
            Console.Write(format, arr.GetValue(loopX));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // These are the arrays to be modified with SetByte.
        short[] shorts = new short[2];

        Console.WriteLine("Initial values of arrays:\n");

        // Display the initial values of the arrays.
        DisplayArray(shorts, "shorts");

        // Copy two regions of source array to destination array,
        // and two overlapped copies from source to source.
        Console.WriteLine("\n" +
            "  Array values after setting byte 1 = 1 and byte 3 = 200\n");
        Buffer.SetByte(shorts, 1, 1);
        Buffer.SetByte(shorts, 3, 10);

        // Display the arrays again.
        DisplayArray(shorts, "shorts");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

`SetByte` should be easy to understand, but if I print the shorts array before doing the `SetByte` operation the array looks like this

```
{short[2]}
    [0]: 0
    [1]: 0
```

After doing the first `Buffer.SetByte(shorts, 1, 1);` the array becomes

```
{short[2]}
    [0]: 256
    [1]: 0
```

And after setting `Buffer.SetByte(shorts, 3, 10);` the array becomes

```
{short[2]}
    [0]: 256
    [1]: 2560
```

At the end, in the example they print the array from right to left:

```
0A00 0100
```

I don't understand how this works, can someone give me to some information about this?

Answer (score 3):

The Buffer class allows you to manipulate memory as if you were using a void pointer in c, it's like a sum of memcpy, memset, and so on to manipulate in a fast way memory on .net .

When you passed the "shorts" array, the Buffer class "sees" it as a pointer to four consecutive bytes (two shorts, each of them two bytes) :

```
  |[0][1]|[2][3]|
   short  short
```

So the uninitialized array looks like this:

```
 |[0][0]|[0][0]|
  short  short
```

When you do `Buffer.SetByte(shorts, 1, 1);` you instruct the Buffer class to change the second byte on the byte array, so it will be:

```
|[0][1]|[0][0]|
 short  short
```

If you convert the two bytes (0x00, 0x01) to a short it is 0x0100 (note as these are the two bytes one after other, but in reverse order, that's because the C# compiler uses little endianness), or 256

The second line basically does the same `Buffer.SetByte(shorts, 3, 10);`changes third byte to 10:

```
|[0][1]|[0][10]|
 short  short
```

And then 0x00,0x0A as a short is 0x0A00 or 2560.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET types use [little endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian). That means that the first byte (0th, actually) of a `short`, `int`, etc. contains the least significant bits.

After setting the array it seems like this as `byte[]`:

```
0, 1, 0, 10
```

As `short[]` it is interpreted like this:

```
0 + 1*256 = 256, 0 + 10*256 = 2560
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the part that people might struggle with is that the `Buffer.SetByte()` method is basically iterating over the array differently than a regular assignment with the array indexer [], which would separate the array according to the width of the containing type(shorts/doubles/etc.) instead of bytes... to use your example:
the short array is usually seen as
`arr = [xxxx, yyyy]`(in base 16)
but the SetByte method "sees" it as:
`arr = [xx, yy, zz, ww]`

so a call like `Buffer.SetByte(arr, 1, 5)` would address the second byte in the arry, which is still inside the first short. setting the value there and that's it. 
the result should look like:

[05 00, 00 00] in hex or [1280,0].